# Full screen responsive background - then normal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image

I'm trying to create a full screen background image that re sizes across devices.

The first content section I want to always appear at the "bottom" of the devices screen after the full image. I've done this already.

I now want to carry on adding `div` elements but the `div` gets pushed back to the top.

I think it may be my position tags..?

**Code**

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FF6969;
}
.moreContent {
  height: 100px;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
html:
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Hello this is my content
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Lots of content
</div>

<div class="moreContent">
  this should be below 'content' div
</div>
```

(also using bootstrap for the real project)

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8xrap3o5/1/)

Comment: so you want the more content divs to appear below the pic?

Comment: huh? I have no idea what you're asking here

Comment: Yes sorry, more content divs to appear below the full screen picture

Comment: Now the divs appear next to each other... do you want all of them to appear at the bottom of the page?

https://jsfiddle.net/8xrap3o5/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are looking for something like this:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FF6969;
  height: 100px;
}
.moreContent {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="content">
    Hello this is my content
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>Lots of content
  </div>

  <div class="moreContent">
    more content...
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I really didn't explain myself very well. Sorry about that. Can you explain the -bottom tags? is this the right way to achieve this design?

Comment: What you need me to explain? the `bottom`has the same negative value as the `height` does. If this answer solves your problem, make sure you mark it as accepted .

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit differently, considering I don't want to keep adding -100px, -200px etc to my div classes. That is a very dirty way of writing css.

So I would create a container Class for all my div elements:-

```
<body> 
  <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
         Hello this is my content
         Lots of contentxxx
      </div>

       <div class="moreContent">
         more content...vcbcvbcv
       </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and then use the following css:-

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/CreativeImages/Hero-527920799.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container{
  bottom:0;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;

}  

.content {
  height: 100px;
   width: 100%;
    background: #FF6969;
}

.moreContent {
    height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
    background: white;
}
```

I personally find it much more general and elegant.
https://jsfiddle.net/8xrap3o5/6/